# Right way to show associativity.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binary-operations, associativity

Authors usually write that $*$ is associative on a set $S$ if,

$(a*b)*c=a*(b*c)$ $\forall a,b,c \in S$

I think it should have been,

$(a*b)*c=a*(b*c)=(a*c)*b$ $\forall a,b,c \in S$

I made all possible groups i.e. $(a,b)$, $(b,c)$ and $(a,c)$ so that for example if set were $\mathbb R$ and operator were "$.$" then I would be able to re write this expression in 3 ways,

$$1.(2.3)=(1.2).3=(1.3).2$$

, which is actually true.

Comment: Multiplication of $2\times2$ matrices is associative according to the "usual" definition. It is not associative according to your definition. Just let $a$ be the identity matrix and $b,c$ any two noncommuting matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with binary operations is that they are defined on just two elements, i.e. $a*b$. Therefore, when it comes to calculating $a∗b∗c$, we don't know how to apply the operation because there are now three elements. This is why we use the brackets, and say "we do $a*b$ first, then we'll apply $c$ to the result", i.e. $(a*b)*c$. Then, in a set where associativity of the binary operation holds, we know it's okay to do $a*(b*c)$ instead of $(a*b)*c$.

The reason why $(a*c)*b$ isn't the same, is because that comes down to helping us answer the question of "what is $a*c*b$?", and this is only ever the same question as "what is $a*b*c$?" when we also have commutativity of the elements $b$ and $c$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Your proposed reformulation assumes commutativity of $*$, which isn't and shouldn't be required for associativity.

Comment: Dylan it is irrespective of commutativity. $a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c=a*(c*b)$ doesn't imply that $a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c=(a*c)*b$. Does it?

Comment: You're assuming $b * c = c * b$ in stating that first equality.

Comment: Dylan I want to say that since associativity is independent of commutativity therefore we should show associativity on a triplet like that , I think.

Comment: That would only be valid for commutative operations, though.

Comment: what? do you mean associativity?

Comment: No, I mean commutativity. You're interchanging $b * c$ with $c * b$.

Comment: DylanSp I didn't applied commutativity. I just made another possible group  i.e. $(a*c)$ beside $(a*b)$ and $(b*c)$.

Answer (score 3):

"Associativity" just means "it doesn't matter how we bracket terms and the order in which we simplify, we'll still get the same answer". It says nothing about the order in which the terms appear. Notice the difference between "the order in which we evaluate the expression" and "the order of the terms in the expression".

Associativity says $(x * y) * (b * c)$ can unambiguously be written as $x*y*b*c$, but it doesn't have anything to do with commutativity. For example, if $*$ is the "concatenation" operation on strings, $x*a*b = xab$ however we perform the concatenation, but it certainly is not equal to $xba$.

Comment: As Lawvere said, "All that matters is the order, not when you take your coffee break."

Comment: "associativity just means that it doesn't matter how we bracket terms and the order in which we simplify..." To implement and show this definition of associativity, we should write $a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c=(a*c)*b$. Because this shows completely what you definition says. No?

Comment: @Man_Of_Wisdom No. $(a * b) * c$ is not necessarily $(a * c) * b$. Let $*$ be the concatenation operation. Then you're attempting to assert that the string $abc$ is the same as the string $acb$.

Comment: @Man_Of_Wisdom Similarly, let $*$ be the composition-of-functions operation. Then you're attempting to assert that for all $x$, have $a(b(c(x))) = a(c(b(x)))$.

Comment: Patrick can you use a simple example? I don't know yet about strings and composition-of-function.

Comment: @Man_Of_Wisdom You don't know what function composition is, but you do know what an associative operation is? Very well. Let $a(x) = x^2, b(x) = \sqrt{x}, c(x) = x+1$, all functions $\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$. Define $f * g: \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ by $f * g: x \mapsto f(g(x))$. Then $(a*b)*c: x \mapsto x+1$, but $(a*c)*b : x \mapsto (\sqrt{x}+1)^2 = x+2 \sqrt{x} + 1$. These are not equal (for example, at $x=1$), so $(a*b)*c \not = (a*c)*b$.

Comment: @Man_Of_Wisdom Function composition is the standard example of an associative operation, and it's what I illustrated above.

Comment: Honestly, I am hearing this word first time. I am a beginner. My textbook doesn't use any term like "Composition-of-function". However I realize that I am familiar with a very little part of this term but still I am not getting what you are trying to explain. So, I am sorry. I wish you explain it in simpler way.

Answer (score 2):

A binary operation ☆ is associative on a set $\mathbb S$ if,

$$(a☆b)☆c=a☆(b☆c) \forall a,b,c \in \mathbb S$$

Suppose you are verifying that whether $\mathbb S$ is associative w.r.t ☆ or not.

Let $x,y,z$ be some definite elements of $\mathbb S$.

Assume you find out that,

$$(x☆y)☆z=x☆(y☆z)$$

Since you have to check associativity according to usual definition and *for all* $a,b,c \in \mathbb S$, you find out associativity holds for another triplet $(x,z,y)$ i.e.

$$(x☆z)☆y=x☆(z☆y)$$

If ☆ is commutative, you can unambigously write;

$$(x☆y)☆z=x☆(y☆z)=(x☆z)☆y$$

, otherwise not.

With your definition, we would have to verify $$(x☆y)☆z=x☆(z☆y)$$

and suppose we had verified

$$(x☆z)☆y=x☆(z☆y)$$

then the following holds if and only if $y☆z=z☆y$

$$(x☆y)☆z=(x☆z)☆y$$

and that would be equivalent to say that *if $☆$ is not commutative, then it's not associative*.